# Unable to load Keras-Tensorflow model after saving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have built my CNN model using Keras (on Tensorflow) and called the `model.save ("location/for/saving")` function and it generated a folder.

Now when I try to load the model using `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model ('location/for/loading')` I get the following error.

```
Two checkpoint references resolved to different objects         
(<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at         
0x7f9b6c1c9100> and 
<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 
0x7f9b6e3efd30>).
WARNING:tensorflow:Inconsistent references when loading the 
checkpoint into this object graph. Either the Trackable object 
references in the Python program have changed in an incompatible 
way, or the checkpoint was generated in an incompatible program.
```

While training for 5 epochs, I had saved my model into the folder at the end of each epoch. Kindly tell what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: I only see a warning, where is the error?

Comment: Can you share complete code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you.Thanks!

Comment: @abhinav-singhal have you solved this problem? I'm facing something similar